# How to repeat an array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

```
$arr = array('1st', '1st');
```

The above `$arr` has `2` items , I want to repeat `$arr` so that it's populated with `4` items

Is there a single call in PHP?

Comment: Any reason to do it with "single call"?

Comment: Possibly related: [How to duplicate values in a flat, indexed array? (Append all elements to end of array in order)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8234899/2943403)

Answer (score 26):

[array_fill](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php) function should help:

```
array array_fill ( int $start_index, int $num, mixed $value )
```

> Fills an array with num entries of the value of the value parameter, keys starting at the start_index parameter.

In your case code will look like:

```
$arr = array_fill(0, 4, '1st');
```

Answer (score 11):

This is a more general answer. In PHP 5.6+ you can use the "splat" operator (`...`) to repeat the array an arbitrary number of times:

```
array_merge(...array_fill(0, $n, $arr));
```

Where `$n` is any integer.

Answer (score 10):

```
$arr = array('1st', '1st');

$arr = array_merge($arr, $arr);
```

Comment: I think this is better because I don't need to bother with the indexes.

Comment: It depends on what do you want to express. If you have an array with some values and you want to double them - use array_merge, and if you want to have an array with predefined number of the same values, then use array_fill. In coding it's not all about you (what is easier for you) it's about easiness to read and understand the code.

Comment: `$arr + $arr` is also a valid option. The main difference between '+' array operator and `array_merge` is the order when overriding values with the same key.