# How to duplicate values in a flat, indexed array? (Append all elements to end of array in order)

Tags: php, arrays

Say I had this code

```
$x = array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e");
```

Is there any function that I could call after creation to duplicate the values, so in the above example `$x` would become

```
array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e");
```

I thought something like the following but it doesn't work.

```
$x = $x + $x;
```

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650177/cant-concatenate-2-arrays-in-php

Comment: @thetaiko, yes order is important

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
$x = array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e");

$x = array_merge($x,$x);
```

Merging an array onto itself will repeat the values as duplicates in sequence.

Answer (score 6):

```
php > $x = array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e");
php > print_r(array_merge($x, $x));

Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
    [2] => c
    [3] => d
    [4] => e
    [5] => a
    [6] => b
    [7] => c
    [8] => d
    [9] => e
)
```

Comment: @Ash - there is also a good summary page that describes all the array functions in PHP quite well: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
$x = array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e");
$x = array_merge($x,$x);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through the array and that each variable to a separate duplicate array. Here is some code off the top of my head:

```
$x = array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e");
$duplicateArray = $array;

foreach ($x as $key) {
    $duplicateArray[] = $key;
}

foreach ($x as $key) {
    $duplicateArray[] = $key;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$x = array_merge($x, $x);
```

Or you could go looping and duplicating, if you preferred.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, it should be asked: Why is it beneficial to push redundant data into your input array?

If you need to access the data in a loop for presentation purposes, you can spare the array bloat and merely change how the elements are iterated.

For instance, you could just call two separate `foreach()` loops on the original array.

```
foreach ($x as $v) {
    echo "$v\n";
}
foreach ($x as $v) {
    echo "$v\n";
}
```

Or with a single `for()` loop, you could use a modulus calculation to access the appropriate element. [Demo](https://3v4l.org/Q3uqZ)

```
$count = count($x);
for ($i = 0, $limit = $count * 2; $i < $limit; ++$i) {
    echo $x[$i % $count] . "\n";
}
```

---

Now, if you do, indeed, need to append the array's values after the original indexed array and maintain the flat, indexed structure, then `array_merge()` is sensible and intuitive, but not the only way.

With the spread/splat operator (`...`), you can unpack the input elements twice inside of a new array. While this is a functionless approach and uses less characters, [it has a habit of not being terribly efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57725812/2943403). [Demo](https://3v4l.org/O0HMG)

```
$result = [...$x, ...$x];
```

---

Perhaps my most-preferred approach would be to call `array_push()` and unpack the elements of the array when pushing data into the original array. I don't know how it performs versus `array_merge()`, but I find it intuitive/literal about the operation of appending data to the original array. [Demo](https://3v4l.org/jh9vL)

```
array_push($x, ...$x);
```

---

For a functional-style approach, `array_reduce()` can have its initial data payload set via its third parameter (in this case the whole input array), then merely push each element one-at-a-time into the result array. [Demo](https://3v4l.org/BDUV1)

```
var_export(
    array_reduce(
        $x,
        function($result, $v) {
            $result[] = $v;
            return $result;
        },
        $x
    )
);
```

---

Although it is unintuitive to use for this task, `array_merge_recursive()` works just like `array_merge()` when fed the indexed array twice. [Demo](https://3v4l.org/oStA3)

```
$result = array_merge_recursive($x, $x)
```

---

After all that, I should warn that there are some techniques to avoid.

1. `$result = array_replace($x, $x);` [is pointless](https://3v4l.org/XKC4I).
2. The [array union operator](https://3v4l.org/pR5lb) is useless.
3. `array_pad()` is unsuitable because its third parameter can only receive one value.
4. `array_map()` returns the same number of elements in its result as its input array.
5. `array_merge(...array_fill(0, 2, $x))` [works](https://3v4l.org/pf0Kb), but why call 2 functions when there 0 and 1-function techniques to enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

If N duplicates of the elements is needed, `array_fill` helps:

https://3v4l.org/3G8c5#v8.2.7

```
$data = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
$multiplicator = 3;
$multipliedData = array_merge(...array_fill(0, $multiplicator, $data));

var_export($multipliedData);
// array (0 => 'a', 1 => 'b', 2 => 'c', 3 => 'a', 4 => 'b', 5 => 'c', 6 => 'a', 7 => 'b', 8 => 'c',)
```