# How to interleavedly duplicate an array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, duplicates, interleave

For instance, I have an array:

```
$x = array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e");
```

Is there any function to iterate all values of array and duplicate the values into:

```
$x = array("a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "d", "d", "e", "e");
```

I've not found any related solution after googled it for a while.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8234899/2943403

Comment: What is your actual use for this technique? Storing redundant data doesn't smell of best practices.  What are you _actually_ doing?

Comment: it's not that similar dude! It's hard to explain but my project requires some conditions that I gotta double the values so I can read them twice when I foreach. Sorry if there's another more effective way to get it done but right now I just think of it.

Comment: It is exactly the same except for the element order.  Adjusting your data is not the solution to your coding problem.

Comment: *so I can read them twice when I foreach*. Why not just do the same thing twice in the loop? `foreach($a as $b){ echo $b; echo $b;}`

Comment: No no. It's like I have two fields and I gotta echo a unique value for both fields each time I foreach.

Comment: It is never too late to clarify your coding problem.  I have voted to close as Unclear.  It is unclear by your posted question and sample data exactly what you need help with.

Comment: @mickmackusa I think you're on the right track here. Closer inspection of this question smells strongly of an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a reasonably simple reduction (using [`array_reduce()`](http://php.net/manual/function.array-reduce.php))

```php
$x = array_reduce($x, function($arr, $val) {
    array_push($arr, $val, $val);
    return $arr;
}, []);
```

Demo ~ https://3v4l.org/eNH8a

---

Just realised that *"reduction"* sounds a bit funny since we're making the array bigger. Think of it more as a *transformation*. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduce_(parallel_pattern)

Comment: I recommend change the body of the reduce function to: `return array_merge($arr, array_pad([], $times, $val));` - this way the `$times` can be change easily - add `use ($times)` to the reduce function declaration

Comment: @dWinder I see what you mean. I feel I could do something more concisely using the PHP _splat_ operator though. I'll have a think about it

Answer (score 1):

Iterating over the array and storing the values in a new array is a simple solution.

```
$x =  array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e");
$result_array = [];
$repeat_x_times = 2;

foreach ($x as $element) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < $repeat_x_times ; $i++) {
        $result_array[] = $element;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is a library function for this, but are you looking for something along the lines of this:

```
function duplicate_array($array=array()) {
    $result = array();
    foreach($array as $elem) {
        $result[] = $elem;
        $result[] = $elem;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

This should in theory do what you want.

```
$x = array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e");

var_dump($x);

$x = duplicate_array($x);

var_dump($x);
```

This should output:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "a"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "b"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "c"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "d"
  [4]=>
  string(1) "e"
}
array(10) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "a"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "a"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "b"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "b"
  [4]=>
  string(1) "c"
  [5]=>
  string(1) "c"
  [6]=>
  string(1) "d"
  [7]=>
  string(1) "d"
  [8]=>
  string(1) "e"
  [9]=>
  string(1) "e"
}
```