# PHP copy x number of array elements in a for loop

Tags: php, arrays

There are probably lots of array questions. But I couldn't find one that answered this specific problem:

I have an associative array as a result from a database query. I loop trough it with a foreach loop. One of the columns contains a number. If that number is larger than 1, I have to duplicate that row x number of times so that the array will have x similiar rows.

I wonder how to do this?

```
foreach( $db_rows as $key => $value )
{  
  if( $value["number"] > 1 )
  //DUPLICATE $value and insert x number of times into $db_rows directly after $key.  
}
```

Comment: what is x or n?

Comment: I assume $db_rows is a numerical array since you say you want it inserted directly after $key?

Comment: X can be 2 or 6, basically a small INT.

Comment: Yes $db_rows has numerical keys.

Comment: `into $db_rows directly after $key.` this to mean you want to insert rows directly after the $key row in the DB?

Comment: @treyBake - yes. If x is 6, I to have 6 identical rows at the same “place” in the array in stead of 1 row

Comment: may be of some use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740358/reorder-reset-auto-increment-primary-key

Comment: I don't think there's really a way to do this in a safe, automated way.. :/

Comment: @johnohod wait.. looking at the answers, in one place you say insert after $db_rows, but in the comments you said yes to insert rows into the DB - which is it?

Comment: This question is both Unclear and Too Broad.  We do not have a [mcve] and it is asking for multiple techniques (multiple questions already answered on Stack Overflow).  We already have [How to repeat an array in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2963777/2943403)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could declare an empty array before the `foreach` loop, then populate it thanks to the 
original, its items' `number` property and a `for` loop:

```php
$clone_db_rows = [];

foreach( $db_rows as $key => $value )
{  
    for ($i = 0; $i < $value['number']; $i++) {
        $clone_db_rows[] = $value;
    }
}
```

Test it [here](https://3v4l.org/kLSUi).

---

**@Andreas** suggests using [`array_fill`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php) to avoid the nested `for` statement.

He's right, and you could do this the following way, with [`array_merge`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php):

```php
$clone_db_rows = [];

foreach( $db_rows as $key => $value )
{  
    $clone_db_rows = array_merge(
        $clone_db_rows,            // Merge the current array with... 
        array_fill(                // ...a newly created one containing...
            0,
            $value['number'],      // ... X items equals to...
            $value                 // ... $value.
        )
    );
}
```

Test it [here](https://3v4l.org/PXeM9).

Comment: I mean.. great, but how does this insert into the db after $key whilst maintaining/fixing the incrementation?

Comment: Array_fill could remove a loop

Comment: @treyBake - The question is about altering an array, not about inserting into the datatabase (or I misread the author's post).

Comment: @KévinBibollet check comment chain (unless OP misunderstood me xD)

Comment: @treyBake - I think you misunderstood each other comment (you talked about BD, he talked about array only), but let's wait the autor's answer. ;)

Comment: @KévinBibollet yeah :) will rm dv in meantime (can't - recent edit has to be done haha)

Comment: Added @Andreas suggestion to my post.

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like this :

```
foreach ($db_rows as $key => $value) {
    if ($value['number'] > 1) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < $value['number'] - 1; $i++) {
            $db_rows[] = $value;
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, he said he wants the values inserted directly after $key

Comment: This also __increases__ number of elements in array and finding another `$value['number']` in later elements will add them again, and again and again. So this foreach __never stops__.

Comment: I also thought of an infinite loop, but it's not the case: because internally, _foreach_ iterates on a copy of the array

Comment: Geoffray is correct. This is not a never ending loop. Foreach uses a copy as he says, a for loop and count() would be a never ending loop. @u_mulder

Answer (score 0):

## Direct Approach:

```php
$array = [
    ["a" => "a", "b" => "aa", "number" => 3, "d" => 1],
    ["a" => "b", "b" => "bb", "number" => 1, "d" => 1],
    ["a" => "c", "b" => "cc", "number" => 3, "d" => 1],
];

foreach($array as $key => $value)
{
    if($value['number'] > 1) {
        array_unshift($array , $value, $value);
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);
```

- take an array
- check sub-array["value"] in conditions for true
- append data at the beginning of the array( use array_push instead of array_unshift to insert at the end of the array)
- this prevents pointer to the array unaffected until the loop ends
- op did not mention any specific restrictions.

note:

check onto optimization.

- EDIT - N+1 times Repeat: + Speed:

```
$output = [];
$times = 2; # set how many times you want to repeat it,

array_map(function($subArray) use(&$output, $times) {
    if($subArray['number']>1) {
        $output = array_merge($output, array_fill(0, $times, $subArray));
    } else {
        array_push($output, $subArray);
    }
}, $array);
```

PS: second approach maintains order for repeating values same value can benefit in better examination on it.

Comment: "this prevents pointer to the array unaffected until the loop ends" - pointer is not disturbed unless you want to

Comment: I guess this also solves my problem. But the order of the elements is a bit strange. I get 2 "a" => "c" in the start of the array, and 1 at the end.

Comment: @johnohod let me check ps: you can have second one working well and Fine I have tested and is good in terms on speed.

Comment: @johnohod I did check that, as well I have mentioned in points,  either you can use array_unshift or array_push.